# ImportError: cannot import name App in Kivy

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy

I have a problem with Kivy on my Ubuntu machine. All of a sudden programs that I execute cannot find the name App.

I don't know the problem however when I run one of the Kivy examples in the examples folder it executes but when I run the same file in a different folder I get the name App error, the file is not dependent of a .kv file. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback and the code that produces it?

Comment: Do you have a file named `kivy.py` where you try to execute it? If that's the case you are shadowing the original kivy.

Comment: @syntonym I do not have a filed named kivy.py in the same folder, however I moved my files to a new folder and that solved the problem. For now that is to be considered problem solved. Thanks you for help!